# How to change propagation on mounted volumes in docker

Tags: docker

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Source": "/home/ec2-user/selenium-downloads",
            "Destination": "/home/seluser/Downloads",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
 ],
```

How can i change Propagation? I need it to be empty so that my docker container can right to the mounted directory.

Comment: Are you sure the [propagration mode](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14630) is the cause of your issue?

Comment: initially i thought its the reason because in my mac the propagation value is public but in the ec2 is rprivate. but later on i found out that its because there is no permission to write to mounted directory.